# Не создаётся контрол из другого AppDomain

Tags: wpf, appdomain

Почему слитает в этом месте (курсивом выделенно)?

```
 public void InitializeComponent() {
            if (_contentLoaded) {
                return;
            }
            _contentLoaded = true;

*System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/AVN.AddInEdoc;component/controls/usercontrol1.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);*

            #line 1 "..\..\..\Controls\UserControl1.xaml"
            System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

            #line default
            #line hidden
        }
```

Выдаёт ошибку:
*Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "AVN.AddInEdoc.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=ru-RU, PublicKeyToken=null" или один из зависимых от них компонентов. Не удается найти указанный файл.*

Это библиотека которую я загружаю в другом AppDomain.
Я тут протестил создал отдельное Windows приложение прикрепил эту библеотеку и там всё работает...

Почему эта ошибка выходит когда я пытаюсь создать UserControl1 контрол из другого AppDomain ?
Может как-то можно запретить что бы неискалось xxx.resources.dll сборка, начинается поиск таких сборок как только начинаю создавать UI элемент в сборке xxx.

Answer (score 1):

Решение [найдено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557792/can-not-create-usercontrol-inside-new-appdomain/18569201#18569201).
Была небольшая ошибка, незнаю как я её допустил, но всё же она была! )